# How to "normalize"(?) a vector after fft in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft, physics, entropy

I want to change from real-space repr. to momentum-space repr. I have a Hamilton-operator (Anderson-model), and I calculated some kind of entropy of its eigenstates (this is working, I see what I want). Next I want to change to momentum repr. using fft, and now my eigenstates in momentum space are not normalized (?). E.g. if I calculate the sum of the eigenstates^2, it has to be 1, but it does not work.

I tried to sum the eigenstates^2 and normalized with them, but It does not work (I show the code without any failed trying).

```
N=100; %dim of matrix
Nx=15; %number of points
%because of log scale
xmin = -3.0;
xmax =  3.0;
dx = (xmax - xmin)/(Nx-1);
x = zeros(1,Nx); %x axis pre
ss = zeros(1,Nx); %entropy pre
spp=zeros(1,Nx); %entropy in Fourier space pre
eps=1.0e-6;

for ix=1:Nx
    %log scale
    x(ix) = xmin + (ix-1)*dx;
    xx = 10.0^x(ix);

    average_s=0;
    average_spp=0;
    %anderson modell
    W=xx;
    r=rand(1,N)*W-(W/2);
    A=diag(ones(1,N-1),1)+diag(ones(1,N-1),-1)+diag(r);
    %diagonalization
    [V,D]=eig(A);
    %PROBLEM HERE:
    %Fourier transformation
    P=fft(V)/(sqrt(2*pi)*N);
    P=abs(P);
    for j=1:N
        four_sum=0; square_sum=0; entropy=0;
        four_sum_p=0; square_sum_p=0; entropyp=0;
        for i=1:N
            %Fou
            probp=(P(i,j)).^2;
            square_sum_p=square_sum_p+probp;
            if probp>eps
                entropyp=entropyp-probp*log(probp);
            end;
            four_sum_p=four_sum_p+probp.^2;

            %Real
            prob=V(i,j).^2;
            square_sum=square_sum+prob;
            if prob>eps
                entropy=entropy-prob*log(prob);
            end;
            four_sum=four_sum+prob.^2;
        end
        qp=square_sum_p.^2/(four_sum_p);
        average_spp=average_spp+entropyp-log(qp);

        q=square_sum.^2/(four_sum);
        average_s=average_s+entropy-log(q);
    end
    ss(ix)=average_s/N;
    spp(ix)=average_spp/N;
end
plot(x,ss,x,spp);
```

The structural entropy in real space (ss vector) has the correct form, but in momentum space (spp) after fft is not look like what I want, and it is not normalized.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you write

```matlab
P = fft(V) / sqrt(N);
```

Because, when I read the FFT help-documentation in Matlab, it shows that the FFT is

```
         N   
X(k) =  Sum  x(n) * exp( -i*2*pi* (k-1) * (n-1)/N ),    1 <= k <= N
        n=1
```

But your matrix of Eigenvectors `V` is unitary and when you switch to momentum space with FFT you need to get a unitary matrix again, so you need the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)  to be a unitary operator (DFT is just a matrix of exponents, as you can see on the matrix equation below). Therefore, to make DFT a unitary transformation, you need the formula

[image]

If you take two different rows of the Discrete Fourier Transform's matrix, say rows `k` and `m`, and form their hermitian dot product you get

[image]

And when you expand and simplify it

[image]

When you look at this sum closer

[image]
[image]

Therefore, the DFT is a unitary matrix, so it converts normalized eigenstates of the Hamiltonain in the position representation to the corresponding normalized eigenstates of the Hamiltonian in the momentum representation.